# Unwanted space between footer and child images

Tags: html, css

I have searched for many similar topics and try many ways but still can't solve this. There's a unwanted space between the bottom boundary of footer and the bottom boundary of the images. If I change the images to display:block, that space will disappear. But I can't explain how this issue happen? Thank you. I can't show any images because of new account.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapperMain">
        <footer>
            <img src="ico/square-facebook.svg"
            /><img src="ico/square-twitter.svg"
            /><img src="ico/square-google-plus.svg"/>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#wrapperMain {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    background:#eeeeee;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: You can see the space in this http://i.imgur.com/nO6TJP7.jpg

Comment: _“If I change the images to display:block, that space will disappear. But I can't explain how this issue happen?”_ – because without `display:block`, the images are aligned to the _baseline_ of (potential) text content of the _line box_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the font-size. Try adding `font-size: 0;` to your `footer` See demo below.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#wrapperMain {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    background:#eeeeee;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapperMain">
        <footer>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/32x32"
            /><img src="http://placehold.it/32x32"
            /><img src="http://placehold.it/32x32"/>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

**Alternatives:**

1. Adding `vertical-align:bottom;` to `img`

example: `img{  vertical-align:bottom; }`

2. Using `line-height: 0` instead of `font-size: 0`

Comment: You can play around with the font-size, try different sizes just to prove that it's really because of it. :)

Comment: The default display for the image is `display:inline`, I think it leave spaces because of the default `vertical-align: baseline`. There are also some other approaches for this. I'll update my answer. 

Sorry but I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Thank you. I think you're right about the reason. Beside, we can add `line-height:0` to `footer`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `margin: 0px;` in the footer or change `bottom:0` to `bottom: 0px;`

Comment: I tried with margin, padding many times, as tried to use many web browsers but that problem still happen. Adding px to 0 value doesn't work either. Thank you.